# Accumarray how to set "fun" to use only last obs of each bin

Tags: matlab, accumarray

Is there a way to let `accumarray` drop every observation but the last of each group?

What I had in mind was something similar:

```
lastobs=accumarray(bin,x,[],@(x){pick the observation with the max index in each group};
```

To give you an example, suppose I have the following:

```
bin=[1 2 3  3 3 4 4];  %#The bin where the observations should be put
x= [21 3 12 5 6 8 31]; %#The vector of observations
%#The output I would like is as follow  
lastobs=[21 3 6 31];
```

I am actually thinking of `accumarray` only because I just used it to compute the mean of the observations for each bin. So every function that could make the trick would be fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can do this with `accumarray`. `x(end)` is the last observation in an array. Note that `bin` needs to be sorted for this to work, so if it isn't, run
`[bin,sortIdx]=sort(bin);x = x(sortIdx);` first.

```
lastobs = accumarray(bin(:),x(:),[],@(x)x(end)); %# bin, x, should be n-by-1
```

Comment: Thank you Jonas, I am still a mess with indexing. I tried tons of combinations but not the easiest one! Glad you are always present to help

Comment: For future readers: `bin` needs to be sorted for this to work correctly!

Comment: @knedlsepp: no, `bin` can be any order, as long as its order corresponds to the order of the elements in `x`. Or can you give an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: For me: `bin = repmat(1:10,1,2); accumarray(bin(:),1:length(bin),[],@(x)x(end))` will output `11    12    13    14     5     6     7    18    19    20` instead of `11:20`. I did write a short [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463433) because of this recent [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460280/) and Luis' answer. The `doc accumarray` lists this behaviour under Input Arguments-fun. It is quite hidden...

Comment: @knedlsepp: Well, TIL. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You already got your [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) answer, but since you are looking for any solution that will do the job, consider the following application of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html).

Using `unique` with the `'legacy'` option gives the index of the *last* occurrence of each value, as you need:

```
>> [~,ia] = unique(bin,'legacy')
ia =
     1     2     5     7
>> lastobs = x(ia)
lastobs =
    21     3     6    31
```

Now, I *love* `accumarray`, as many here are aware, but I actually prefer this solution.

Comment: Thanks chappjc, I am pretty new to matlab and every answer is something I can learn from. Anyway, I will work with the biggest series tomorrow, I will check both solutions and see which one is the fastest. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: @Gio `accumarray` is _really fast_ in most cases, but perhaps with this specific `fun` it could be a bit slower.