# How can I find the last element amongst a set of grouping variables?

Tags: matlab

I have a 150x2 matrix in which the first column contains numbers that can be considered 'grouping variables' and the second column contains values associated with those grouping variables. So a small 12x2 version would look like this

```
 200741 5441
 200741 5524
 200741 5428
 200742 5670
 200742 5668
 200742 5559
 200742 5215
 200743 5184
 200743 5473
 200743 5496
 200743 5568
 200743 5702
```

I'd like to find the last value of the values associated with each grouping variable. So the above example would yield a last element of 5428(for variable 200741), last element of 5215(for variable 200742) & last element of 5702(for grouping variable 200743). After I find the unique vales of grouping variables in coumn1, how do I take the last element in column2 corresponding to each grouping variable? How could this be done in Matlab ?

Comment: Just curious - Did any of the solutions posted here work for you?

Answer (score 4):

If the first column is *sorted* and contains *positive integers*, you could use [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) (admittedly stretching it a little):

```
result = nonzeros(accumarray(A(:,1), A(:,2), [], @(x) x(end), 0, true));
```

Notes:

- The sorting requirement stems from the fact that, according to the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html),

  > If the subscripts in `subs` are not sorted with respect to their linear indices, then `accumarray` might not always preserve the order of the data in val when it passes them to `fun`

  and so `@(x) x(end)` would not always give the *last* element.
- The sparse version of `accumarray` (fifth argument `true`) is used in case the grouping values are large (as in the example).

Comment: @Divakar The key is `@(x) x(end)` (together with the quoted remark): take the last element from each group. But yes, I forced things a little. You guys left little room with your great answers! :-)

Comment: Hmm that sort of makes sense now!

Answer (score 3):

This could be one approach, assuming `A` as the input array  -

```
%// Sort the input matrix based on the column -1 values, 
%// just for cases when the "grouping variables" are not already sorted
A = sortrows(A,1)

%// Use diff to find out the row indices where "groups" switch
%// to give us the last row indices for each "grouping", which
%// could be used to index into second column of A for final output
out = A([diff(A(:,1))~=0 ; true],2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the matrix is sorted by the grouping numbers, as in the example, to get a boolean indices you can do something like this:
given your matrix is `a`

```
I=a(1:end-1, 1) ~= a(2:end, 1)
```

It will store boolean ones on the indices corresponding to the last "grouping" numbers, except the last one.
So to get the rows you want just perform `a(I, :)`. And don't forget the last result.
Or, as a one-liner:

```
[a( a(1:end-1, 1) ~= a(2:end, 1), : ); a(end, :)]
```

Comment: You should perhaps indicate that this assumes that the matrix is sorted according to first column

Comment: @LuisMendo Done, although there is not much sense of talking about the "last" value, if not sorted.

Comment: Consider for example `[10 1; 10 2; 20 5; 10 4]`. The last values are `4` (for `10`) and `5` (for `20`). The matrix is not sorted

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unique` to give you the locations of the first or last occurrences of a number; depending on version you may need to use the `legacy` option to make sure it returns the `last` index:

```
[B,ind,~] = unique(A(:,1),'last','legacy');
out = A(ind,2);
```

Comment: I was about to suggest this one!

Comment: What, no `bsxfun`? ;)  I get the impression OP is going to be pulling the `unique` values from the first column anyway, might as well go for the twofer.

Comment: @nkjt Will `accumarray` do? :-)