# Split up a matrix based on numbers in two columns

Tags: matlab

I have a large matrix in which I want to separate the rows based on the values of two columns. For example:

```
M=[ 1 3 5 6; 3 6 5 4; 1 8 5 1; 4 6 5 7; 3 6 4 5; 3 6 4 4]
```

I want the rows to be separated by the common values seen in columns 1 and 3 simultaneously.  This is the expected output:

```
A= [1 3 5 6; 1 8 5 1]
B= [3 6 5 4]
C= [4 6 5 7]
D= [3 6 4 5; 3 6 4 4]
```

I've tried the following.  However, it only separates it by a single column:

```
A = arrayfun(@(x) M(M(:,1) == x, :), unique(M(:,1)), 'uniformoutput', false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's my understanding that you want to extract out rows of a matrix where they all share common values along the first and third columns.  You can certainly use the `arrayfun` approach, but you'll need to modify how you call `unique`.  Specifically, use the `'rows'` flag on the columns that you want to examine, then inside your `arrayfun` call, use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) combined with  [`all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html)to check for those rows that contain each unique combination of column elements you want, so:

```
>> M=[ 1 3 5 6; 3 6 5 4; 1 8 5 1; 4 6 5 7; 3 6 4 5; 3 6 4 4];
>> r = unique(M(:,[1 3]), 'rows', 'stable');
>> A = arrayfun(@(x) M(all(bsxfun(@eq, M(:,[1 3]), r(x,:)),2), :), 1:size(r,1),'uni', 0);
>> celldisp(A);

A{1} =

     1     3     5     6
     1     8     5     1

A{2} =

     3     6     5     4

A{3} =

     4     6     5     7

A{4} =

     3     6     4     5
     3     6     4     4
```

It's important to note that I use the `'stable'` flag, because `unique` by default **sorts** the unique entries.  `'stable'` ensures that we find unique entries **in the order** in which we encounter them, like the desired output that is seen in your question.  BTW, `'uni'` is short for `'UniformOutput'`.  It'll save you typing in the long run :).

The third line is quite a mouthful, but very easy to explain.  First, take a look at this statement:

```
bsxfun(@eq, M(:,[1 3]), r(x,:))
```

What we will do here is we take each row of `r`, which is a unique pairing of values taken from columns 1 and 3 of `M`, and see whether each value in a row of `M` is equal to the corresponding location in a row from `r`.  In order to find a match, we need to make sure that **all** values from a row of this result are equal to 1, which is why we need to use `all` here and look across the columns:

```
all(bsxfun(@eq, M(:,[1 3]), r(x,:)),2)
```

Once we find these rows that match with a particular row in `r`, we use these and index into our matrix `M` and extract the rows that satisfy the row in `r` we are looking for in `M` and therefore:

```
M(all(bsxfun(@eq, M(:,[1 3]), r(x,:)),2), :)
```

`x` iterates from 1 up to as many rows as there are in `r`, and at each iteration, we extract out a unique row from `r` each time.  The end result will be a cell array that groups rows of `M` based on common elements between the first and third columns.

---

If you want this to be more efficient, you can do what Divakar suggested and use only the third output of `unique`.  This'll make things easier to read too:

```
>> M=[ 1 3 5 6; 3 6 5 4; 1 8 5 1; 4 6 5 7; 3 6 4 5; 3 6 4 4];
>> [~,~,r] = unique(M(:,[1 3]), 'rows', 'stable');
>> A = arrayfun(@(x) M(r == x, :), 1:max(r),'uni', 0);
>> celldisp(A);

A{1} =

     1     3     5     6
     1     8     5     1

A{2} =

     3     6     5     4         

A{3} =

     4     6     5     7

A{4} =

     3     6     4     5
     3     6     4     4
```

Certainly more readable!  What's happening now is that the third output of `unique` assigns a unique ID from 1 up to as many unique values that you have that serves as the input into `unique`.  Then, we simply find the maximum ID, and iterate from 1 up to the maximum ID, where at each iteration, this index serves as a way of extracting out the rows that correspond to each unique combination of the first and third columns from the matrix `M`.

Comment: Except you can use the third output from `unique` and hence avoid `bsxfun`.

Answer (score 1):

For me partitioning means `accumarray` in MATLAB. The first step is basically the same as in *rayryeng*'s solution: Use `unique` to get the new positions of each row. The second step is: Based on those new positions: fetch the rows of `M` and put them in a cell.

```
[~,~,I] = unique(M(:,[1 3]), 'rows', 'stable');
A = accumarrayStable(I, 1:length(I), [], @(J) {M(J,:)});
```

As these row-positions won't be sorted we need a stable version of `accumarray`, which I take from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463434/3139711).
If you don't care about the order of the rows in each `A{i}`, you won't need this, but can go with the faster `accumarray` right away.

```
function A = accumarrayStable(subs, val, varargin)
[subs(:,end:-1:1), I] = sortrows(subs(:,end:-1:1));
A = accumarray(subs, val(I), varargin{:});
```

Overall going with this solution should give you a 5-10x speedup with respect to the `arrayfun`-solution, depending on your matrix size of course.

Comment: Seems really fast indeed! Good job.