# Speed up arrayfun

Tags: matlab

I have a very large Matlab table of about 11 million rows, that I would like to rearrange to have an cell array for each instance of one of the variables. The following smaller data set will illustrate my problem:

```
Data = table(repmat(randperm(50).',200,1),rand(10000,1),'VariableNames',{'ID','VAR'});
```

I am able to perform the task by the following command, but it is quite slow when applied to my real table:

```
UniID = unique(Data.ID);

CellData = arrayfun(@(x)Data(Data.ID==x,:),UniID,'UniformOutput',false);
```

What can I do to optimize the execution time?

Comment: Maybe get `Data.ID` into a separate variable?

Comment: Also try use a for loop instead of `arrayfun`, there might be less overhead...

Comment: Getting rid of `table` will probably be the best way to speed this up.

Comment: Putting `Data.ID` into a separate variable, did a little, but not a lot. I can also try the for loop. I my real table I have a lot of variables and some of them are not numeric, so I not sure how to avoid table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may want to do some processing after this, consider using:

```
B = varfun(@(x) {x}, Data, 'GroupingVariables', 'ID');
```

You can either use this to partition the values into groups like presented above, or directly apply some function like `mean`, if you change `@(x) {x}` to `@mean`. This should be the clearest solution, yet it won't give you any speed gains.

---

You might however get a little speed gain, if you don't use tables, but simply use arrays. There instead of `'GroupingVariables'`, you would use `accumarray`.

If your `Data.ID`s are positive integers already you don't need any preprocessing step (If they aren't use: `[~,~,newID] = unique(ID)`) and can just use:

```
accumarray(Data.ID, Data.VAR, [], @(x) {x})
```

If your table only has two variables, this will be sufficient. If you are dealing with more than one variable, you will have to use something similar:

```
accumarray(Data.ID, 1:size(Data,1) ,[], @(I) {Data(I,:)})
```

Both of these will likely shuffle the internal ordering of each cell-entry. If you don't want this, use [this stable version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463434/3139711) of `accumarray`.

As the table data-structure has some overhead, this will possibly be even faster, if you don't use the `Data` table to access the values, but the arrays themselves:

```
VAR1 = rand(100000,1);
VAR2 = rand(100000,1);
ID = repmat(randperm(50).',2000,1);
VARsPartitioned = accumarray(ID, 1:numel(ID) ,[], @(I) {[VAR1(I,:), VAR2(I,:)]});
```

---

For a million rows and 5000 different IDs, I get these results:

```
arrayfun:                ~30 seconds
varfun:                  ~30 seconds
accumarray using table:  ~3 seconds
accumarray using arrays: ~0.3 seconds
```

PS: You can also use something like `@mean` or `@std` directly with `accumarray` without the need to group the variables in a first step.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like avoiding `table` and `arrayfun`, and using `accumarray` instead is the way to go...

Comment: In my real data, the IDs are positive integers, but they don't run from consecutively from 1 to 50, but might start at 7100 and is not consecutive from 7100. I can't see how I adjust your last solution to this?

Comment: @Mace: If I understand correctly, you don't want there to be any 'holes'; yes you can use `unique` there. If you don't mind the holes, it should work though.