# Fastest way of finding and multiplying repeated values in array

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

What is the fastest way of finding and multiplying repeated values between them in an array?

Example:

```
a = [ 2 2 3 5 11 11 17 ]
```

Result:

```
a = [ 4 3 5 121 17 ]
```

I can think of iterative ways (by finding the hist, iterating through bins, ...) , but is there a vectorized/fast approach?

Comment: As I just had a look at the other answers: What is the expected output for `a = [2 2 3 3 2 2]`? Divakar's answer yields `[4,9,4]`, whereas thewaywewalk's answer yields `[16,9]`.

Comment: @knedlsepp To be honest, it wont happen. But well, chose the one you prefer. I would say 2nd option fits more in what I was doing, but it doesn't matter. Nice you noticed it though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [**`histc`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) and [**`unique`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
ua = unique(a)
out = ua.^histc(a,ua)
```

---

```
out =

     4     3     5   121    17
```

---

Considering the case, that the vector `a` is **not monotonically increasing**, it gets a little more complicated:

```
%// non monotonically increasing vector
a = [ 2 2 3 5 11 11 17 4 4 1 1 1 7 7]

[ua, ia] = unique(a)             %// get unique values and sort as required for histc  
[~, idx] = ismember(sort(ia),ia) %// get original order
hc = histc(a,ua)                 %// count occurences
prods = ua.^hc                   %// calculate products
out = prods(idx)                 %// reorder to original order
```

or:

```
ua = unique(a,'stable')          %// get unique values in original order
uas = unique(a)                  %// get unique values sorted as required for histc  
[~,idx] = ismember(ua,uas)       %// get indices of original order
hc = histc(a,uas)                %// count occurences
out = ua.^hc(idx)                %// calculate products and reorder
```

---

```
out =

     4     3     5   121    17    16     1    49
```

Seems still a good solution as `accumarray` also [**doesn't offer a stable version by default**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463433/stable-accumarray-in-matlab).

Comment: OH, well, Divakar's answer is cool, but this one is short and clear! Very nice.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer for the length and clarity of the code, however both of them are really good.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Have a look at my edit, I don't know if it applies to your case.

Comment: Very nice! In my case they are monotonically increasing, but this is very nice for the community.

Comment: Could you check the output for `a = [ 2 2 3 5 11 11 17 4 4 1 1 1 7 7]`?

Comment: @Divakar thanks for your advice! I misused sort.... I stole your ismember approach now. My upvote you already had anyway :)

Comment: The non-monotonic version doesn't work for me with `a = randi(30,1000,1);` Haven't found the bug yet though.

Comment: Oh. I guess the problem is the following: Multiple non-consecutive occurrences of the same integer: `a = [2 2 3 3 2 2]`.

Comment: @knedlsepp that is true. that won't work, but is also far from the OPs request.

Comment: @thewaywewalk: Yup, he clarified that this case won't occur, so it doesn't matter. In this sense it is not a bug, but rather one possible interpretation of the problem.

Answer (score 6):

### Prospective approach and Solution Code

Seems like the posted problem would be a good fit for [`accumarray`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) -

```
%// Starting indices of each "group"
start_ind = find(diff([0 ; a(:)]))

%// Setup IDs for each group
id = zeros(1,numel(a)) %// Or id(numel(a))=0 for faster pre-allocation
id(start_ind) = 1

%// Use accumarray to get the products of elements within the same group
out = accumarray(cumsum(id(:)),a(:),[],@prod)
```

For a **non monotonically increasing** input, you need to add two more lines of code -

```
[~,sorted_idx] = ismember(sort(start_ind),start_ind)
out = out(sorted_idx)
```

Sample run -

```
>> a
a =
     2     2     3     5    11    11    17     4     4     1     1     1     7     7
>> out.'
ans =
     4     3     5   121    17    16     1    49
```

---

### Tweaky-Squeaky

Now, one can make use of [`logical indexing`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html#btjk576-1) to remove `find` and also use the
faster pre-allocation scheme to give the proposed approach a *super-boost* and give us a **tweaked code** -

```
id(numel(a))=0;
id([true ; diff(a(:))~=0])=1;
out = accumarray(cumsum(id(:)),a(:),[],@prod);
```

---

### Benchmarking

Here's the benchmarking code that compares all the proposed approaches posted thus far for the stated problem for runtimes -

```
%// Setup huge random input array
maxn = 10000;
N = 100000000;
a = sort(randi(maxn,1,N));

%// Warm up tic/toc.
for k = 1:100000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

disp('------------------------- With UNIQUE')
tic
ua = unique(a);
out = ua.^histc(a,ua);
toc, clear ua out

disp('------------------------- With ACCUMARRAY')
tic
id(numel(a))=0;
id([true ; diff(a(:))~=0])=1;
out = accumarray(cumsum(id(:)),a(:),[],@prod);
toc, clear out id

disp('------------------------- With FOR-LOOP')
tic
b = a(1);
for k = 2:numel(a)
    if a(k)==a(k-1)
        b(end) = b(end)*a(k);
    else
        b(end+1) = a(k);
    end
end
toc
```

**Runtimes**

```
------------------------- With UNIQUE
Elapsed time is 3.050523 seconds.
------------------------- With ACCUMARRAY
Elapsed time is 1.710499 seconds.
------------------------- With FOR-LOOP
Elapsed time is 1.811323 seconds.
```

**Conclusions:** The runtimes it seems, support the idea of `accumarray` over the two other approaches!

Comment: I was expecting a nice answer like this from you Divakar!

Comment: @AnderBiguri Ah me too! ;)

Comment: @Divakar: What version of MATLAB are you running? Copy pasting your code I get entirely different results. (Macbook Pro 4GB RAM, R2014a):
`unique`: 12.3 seconds, `accumarray`: 9.8 seconds, `for`: 2.9 seconds.

Comment: It seems `N=1e8` is too much memory for my machine for `accumarray`. `N=1e7` results are more similar, yet still the `for` loop beats `accumarray` here: `unique`: 0.94s, `accumarray`: 0.31s, `for`: 0.26s.

Comment: @knedlsepp I am on 2015A, 16GB RAM. Make it `N = 1000000` and `maxn = 100`? The idea is to use such datasizes for which tic-toc results in more than 1 sec runtimes, that lessens the effect of variations that come up with using tic-toc.

Comment: @Divakar: Ok, this is obviously due to the lower memory overhead of the loop approach then. The slight performance difference of `accumarray` and `for` could be version or hardware related. However it's surprising to me how good the JIT acceleration has become. When I was first taught MATLAB the general consensus was basically: Never ever use a `for`-loop unless you really have to. It's great to see that has changed, as sometimes the loopy approach is so much easier to understand.

Comment: @knedlsepp Agreed, it's hard to beat loopy codes at times these days! Hardware does play a good role anyway. Well, I wouldn't know what they teach in MATLAB classes, never been to one of those!

Answer (score 3):

You might be surprised how well a simple `for`-loop compares in terms of speed:

```
b = a(1);
for k = 2:numel(a)
    if a(k)==a(k-1)
        b(end) = b(end)*a(k);
    else
        b(end+1) = a(k);
    end
end
```

Even without doing any preallocation this performs on par with the `accumarray` solution.

Comment: Added few tweaks and benchmarks for more surprises :) Good alternative solution though!