# Reverse lookup with non-unique values

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization, reverse-lookup

## What I'm trying to do

I have an array of numbers:

```
>> A = [2 2 2 2 1 3 4 4];
```

And I want to find the array indices where each number can be found:

```
>> B = arrayfun(@(x) {find(A==x)}, 1:4);
```

In other words, this `B` should tell me:

```
>> for ii=1:4, fprintf('Item %d in location %s\n',ii,num2str(B{ii})); end
Item 1 in location 5
Item 2 in location 1  2  3  4
Item 3 in location 6
Item 4 in location 7  8
```

It's like the 2nd output argument of `unique`, but instead of the first (or last) occurrence, I want *all* the occurrences. I think this is called a reverse lookup (where the original key is the array index), but please correct me if I'm wrong.

## How can I do it faster?

What I have above gives the correct answer, but it scales terribly with the number of unique values. For a real problem (where `A` has 10M elements with 100k unique values), even this stupid for loop is 100x faster:

```
>> B = cell(max(A),1);
>> for ii=1:numel(A), B{A(ii)}(end+1)=ii; end
```

But I feel like this can't possibly be the best way to do it.

We can assume that `A` contains only integers from 1 to the max (because if it doesn't, I can always pass it through `unique` to make it so).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a simple task for [**`accumarray`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
out = accumarray(A(:),(1:numel(A)).',[],@(x) {x})  %'

out{1} = 5
out{2} = 3 4 2 1
out{3} = 6
out{4} = 8 7
```

---

However `accumarray` suffers from not being **stable** (in the sense of `unique`'s feature), so you might want to have a look [**here for a stable version of accumarray**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463433/stable-accumarray-in-matlab), if that's a problem.

---

Above solution also assumes `A` to be filled with integers, preferably with no gaps in between. If that is not the case, there is no way around a call of `unique` in advance:

```
A = [2.1 2.1 2.1 2.1 1.1 3.1 4.1 4.1];

[~,~,subs] = unique(A)
out = accumarray(subs(:),(1:numel(A)).',[],@(x) {x})
```

---

To sum up, the most generic solution, working with floats and returning a sorted output could be:

```
[~,~,subs] = unique(A)
[subs(:,end:-1:1), I] = sortrows(subs(:,end:-1:1));  %// optional
vals = 1:numel(A);                                   
vals = vals(I);                                      %// optional
out = accumarray(subs, vals , [],@(x) {x});

out{1} = 5
out{2} = 1 2 3 4
out{3} = 6
out{4} = 7 8
```

---

### Benchmark

```
function [t] = bench()
    %// data
    a = rand(100);
    b = repmat(a,100);
    A = b(randperm(10000));

    %// functions to compare
    fcns = {
        @() thewaywewalk(A(:).');
        @() cst(A(:).');
    }; 

    % timeit
    t = zeros(2,1);
    for ii = 1:100;
        t = t + cellfun(@timeit, fcns);
    end
    format long
end

function out = thewaywewalk(A) 
    [~,~,subs] = unique(A);
    [subs(:,end:-1:1), I] = sortrows(subs(:,end:-1:1));
    idx = 1:numel(A);
    out = accumarray(subs, idx(I), [],@(x) {x});
end
function out = cst(A) 
    [B, IX] = sort(A);
    out  = mat2cell(IX, 1, diff(find(diff([-Inf,B,Inf])~=0)));
end
```

---

```
0.444075509687511  %// thewaywewalk
0.221888202987325  %// CST-Link
```

Surprisingly the version with stable `accumarray` is faster than the unstable one, due to the fact that Matlab prefers sorted arrays to work on.

Comment: why the sortrows() and not just sort?

Comment: @Oleg the explanation is in the linked answer: *We can use sortrows as a preprocessing step to sort the indices and corresponding values first SORTROWS uses a stable version of quicksort*

Comment: This also confused me at first, but my understanding is that `sortrows` and the `end:-1:1` column ordering are used in the linked answer to properly handle multi-dimensional subscripts. In this particular case, `subs` is always a vector and so `sort` and `sortrows` are equivalent.

Comment: @thewaywewalk nice linked answer. That is probably also where performance is lost.  I usually use `accumarray()` to `mat2cell()` an array since it is faster, but I do not care about preserving order.

Answer (score 3):

This solution should work in O(N*log(N)) due sorting, but is quite memory intensive (requires 3x the amount of input memory):

```
[U, X] = sort(A);
    B  = mat2cell(X, 1, diff(find(diff([Inf,U,-Inf])~=0)));
```

I am curious about the performance though.

Comment: It is (surprisingly, I admit) fast!