# How can I create an array of matrices from a single matrix by using first column as index?

Tags: matlab, matrix, machine-learning, pattern-matching, naivebayes

Suppose, I have the following matrix,

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
2   3   4   5   6   7   8   1 
3   4   5   6   7   8   1   2 
4   5   6   7   8   1   2   3
1   8   7   6   5   4   3   2
2   7   6   5   4   3   2   9
3   6   5   4   3   2   9   8 
4   5   4   3   2   9   8   7
```

I want to create an array of 4 matrices, classified according to the column # 1.

For instance, the output should be like the following,

```
[ 
  2 3 4 5 6 7 8
  8 7 6 5 4 3 2

  3 4 5 6 7 8 1
  7 6 5 4 3 2 9 

  4 5 6 7 8 1 2
  6 5 4 3 2 9 8

  5 6 7 8 1 2 3
  5 4 3 2 9 8 7 
]
```

My target is to apply [this Parzen function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/146269/3804) to each of them.

---

**Is it something like the following?**

```
function [retval] = bayes (train, test)

    classCounts = rows(unique(train(:,1)));
    pdfmx = ones(rows(test), classCounts);

    variance = 0.25;
    pdf = parzen(train(:,2:end), test(:,2:end), variance);

    for cl=1:classCounts
        clidx = train(:,1) == cl;
        mu(:,cl) = train(clidx,2:end);      
    end
    retval = mu;
endfunction
```

This code is generating the following error,

```
>> bayes(mat, mat)
error: bayes: A(I,J,...) = X: dimensions mismatch
error: called from
    bayes at line 11 column 12
>>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a classic job for [**`accumarray`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). It outputs a cell array, but I recommend you to continue with a 3D-matrix.

```
%// data
A = [1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
     2   3   4   5   6   7   8   1 
     3   4   5   6   7   8   1   2 
     4   5   6   7   8   1   2   3
     1   8   7   6   5   4   3   2
     2   7   6   5   4   3   2   9
     3   6   5   4   3   2   9   8 
     4   5   4   3   2   9   8   7]

%// input
groupid = A(:,1);      %// group identifier
rowidx = 1:size(A,1);  %// row index

%// accumarray
cellArray = accumarray(groupid(:),rowidx (:),[],@(x) {A(x,2:end)})

%// transform cell array to 3D-Matrix
threeDArray = cat(3,cellArray{:})
```

### Explanation

What does `accumarray`?

- It takes all elements of `vals = rowidx` with the same `subs = groupid`, groups it and performs an action.
- As you want to perform an action on rows of a matrix and not a single vector, but vector input is required, you "trick" accumarray by actually introducing the row indices as input, which you than use within the function applied
- `A(x,2:end)` means you take all `rowidx` with the same `groupid` stored in `x` and you use it to access your matrix `A`, you put `{}` around to get a cell array output

---

```
cellArray{1} =
     8     7     6     5     4     3     2
     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
cellArray{2} =
     7     6     5     4     3     2     9
     3     4     5     6     7     8     1
cellArray{3} =
     6     5     4     3     2     9     8
     4     5     6     7     8     1     2 
cellArray{4} =
     5     4     3     2     9     8     7
     5     6     7     8     1     2     3
```

---

```
threeDArray(:,:,1) =
     8     7     6     5     4     3     2
     2     3     4     5     6     7     8  
threeDArray(:,:,2) =
     7     6     5     4     3     2     9
     3     4     5     6     7     8     1
threeDArray(:,:,3) =
     6     5     4     3     2     9     8
     4     5     6     7     8     1     2
threeDArray(:,:,4) =
     5     4     3     2     9     8     7
     5     6     7     8     1     2     3
```

---

If the order of rows in the output is important, you need a "stable version" of `accumarray` (inspired by [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463433/stable-accumarray-in-matlab/28463434#28463434):

```
%// stabilize accumarray
sz = max(groupid,[],1);
[~, I] = sort(groupid*cumprod([1,sz(1:end-1)]).');

%// stable accumarray
cellArray = accumarray(groupid(I,:),rowidx(I),[],@(x) {A(x,2:end)})
```

---

```
cellArray{1} =
     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
     8     7     6     5     4     3     2
cellArray{2} =
     3     4     5     6     7     8     1
     7     6     5     4     3     2     9
cellArray{3} =
     4     5     6     7     8     1     2
     6     5     4     3     2     9     8
cellArray{4} =
     5     6     7     8     1     2     3
     5     4     3     2     9     8     7
```

---

```
threeDArray(:,:,1) =
     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
     8     7     6     5     4     3     2
threeDArray(:,:,2) =
     3     4     5     6     7     8     1
     7     6     5     4     3     2     9
threeDArray(:,:,3) =
     4     5     6     7     8     1     2
     6     5     4     3     2     9     8
threeDArray(:,:,4) =
     5     6     7     8     1     2     3
     5     4     3     2     9     8     7
```

Comment: `cellArray = accumarray(subs(:),vals(:),[],@(x) {A(x,2:end)})` this is very hard to understand.

Comment: @anonymous have a look at my edit, together with the doc it should be clearer now